# How do I convert php m.d.Y date to Unix timestamp?

Tags: php, strtotime

I'm receiving date something like 11.30.2012 which I need to convert in UNIX timestamp but in PHP seems it's not working. How can I resolve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just figured it out. As it's an invalid date format so I had to replace '.' with '/' or any other valid symbol for date.

$date = "11.30.2012";
echo str_replace('.','/', $date);

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = '12.31.2000';

$timestamp = DateTime::createFromFormat('m.d.Y', $date)->getTimestamp();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$date = "11.30.2012";

$x = explode(".",$date);

$req_date = $x[2]."-".$x[0]."-".$x[1];

$unixdate = strtotime($req_date);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$date = "11.30.2012"; 
list($month, $day, $year) = split('.', $date); 
$timeStamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year);
```